# Is there a way to use a custom Angular Directive to apply a ngIf "effect"?

Tags: angular

I have an application which has a Role based access. I'm using `*ngIf`'s to allow/block users from access some components.

Is there a way to use a custom directive that will process the "existence" of the component based on the user role; instead of a complete `*ngIf` condition like this:

```
<admin-menu *ngIf="user.role =='admin'"></admin-menu>

<admin-menu my-custom-directive ></admin-menu>

    my-custom-directive {
    
    //make the component where this directive is attached render or vanish based on the user.role
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if(user.role == 'admin'){
            //render the component
        } else {
            //vanish the component
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TemplateRef` and `ViewContainerRef` to create custom `*ngIf` directive. For example:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[claims]'
})
export class CustomNgIfDirective {

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ){}

    @Input()
    set claims(claims) {
        let createEmbeddedView: boolean = false;

        if(claims) {
            if(Array.isArray(claims)) {
                createEmbeddedView = claims.every((passedClaim: string | number) => {
                    return claimExists(passedClaim);
                });
            } else {
                createEmbeddedView = claimExists(claims);
            }
        } else {
            createEmbeddedView = true;
        }

        if(createEmbeddedView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
    }

}
```

And in the html:

```html
<button *claims="'canSubmitClaim'">submit</button>
```

Comment: Perfect @Superiom
Thx alot. I modified the condition to my proper role feature and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can use structural directive for this purpose. It is super easy and it can be used in this way `*appIfRole=""`. Exactly same as `*ngIf`.

Just refer this URL - https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

And https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive

Answer (score 0):

For the role base access to the user you can you the auth guard service.
This is the API link `https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate`.